# Maximum of a $f(x)=(x_{1}\cdot x_{2}\cdot...\cdot x_{n})^{2}$ over the sphere $S_{n-1}$

Tags: inequality, maxima-minima

Yesterday I was looking in my Math Analysis book and I found this problem, which I'm very interested about cause I think it's not that easy. Can someone solve it? I tried but nothing came out of my mind.

> Let $f$ be a function defined by:
>   $$f(x)=(x_{1}\cdot x_{2}\cdot...\cdot x_{n})^{2}$$ 
>   and $S_{n-1}:=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ : $\|x\|_{2}=1\}$.
>
> (1) Show that $\underset{x\in S_{n-1}}{\max}f(x)=\frac{1}{n^{n}}.$
>
> (2) Use the (1) to prove that 
>   $|(x_1\cdot x_2\cdot...\cdot x_n)|\leq\|x\|_{2}^{n}\cdot\frac{1}{n^{(n/2)}}$.
>
> (3) Deduce from (1) that if $x=(x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n})$ has only positive
>   value-coordinates, so
>   $$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}}{n}\geq\sqrt[n]{(x_{1}\cdot x_{2}\cdot...\cdot x_{n})}.$$

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Have you heard of Lagrange multiplier?

Answer (score 1):

Hint. By [AM-GM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means),
$$(f(x))^{1/n}=\left((x_{1}\cdot x_{2}\cdot\dots\cdot x_{n})^{2}\right)^{1/n}\leq \frac{x_{1}^2+ x_{2}^2+\dots+x_{n}^2}{n}=\frac{\|x\|_2^2}{n}.$$

Comment: Can you help me a little more? I don't know how to continue from that point..

Comment: @MrtLpa  My hint is not a small hint... Try something!

Comment: Isn't the deduction (3) precisely AM-GM?

Comment: Ok, I'm going to, thanks :)

Comment: I'm sorry.. I've tried and retried.. but I didn't came up with a solution. I don't know what to look for.. Could you please help me? thanks

Comment: I know what am gm inequality is, but I cannot prove any of these points..

Comment: I'm not so sure.. can you show me how to do it? thanks a lot

Comment: @Albi_23 Please show your attempt  and I will tell you my opinion!!

Answer (score 0):

One wants to say "By symmetry, all the $x_{i}$ must be equal". This simplification makes the problem trivial - the constraint becomes $nx_{i}^{2} = 1$, and the bound follows.

Since $S_{n-1}$ is a closed and bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, $f$ does attain a maximum somewhere. Let's try to prove that in order to maximise $f$, all the $x_{i}$ should be equal. Suppose $x_{i} \ne x_{j}$. Then the average $$\frac{x_{i}^{2}+x_{j}^{2}}{2}$$
is different from $x_{i}^{2}$ and $x_{j}^{2}$. Now suppose we replace $x_{i}$ and $x_{j}$ by $\bar{x} = \left((x_{i}^{2}+x_{j}^{2})/2\right)^{1/2}$
Then $||x||_{2}$ is still $1$, but we have the identity
$$\left(\frac{x_{i}^{2}+x_{j}^{2}}{2}\right)^{2}=\left(\frac{x_{i}^{2}-x_{j}^{2}}{2}\right)^{2}+x_{i}^{2}x_{j}^{2}>x_{i}^{2}x_{j}^{2}$$
so the value of $f$ strictly increases! Therefore if $f$ is maximal, $x_{1}=x_{2} = \ldots =x_{n}$. Can you finish it from there?

Comment: I'm not so sure.. Due to it's not being for a test or something like that, but just for my personal knowledge, can you bring me to the end of the demonstration? thanks a lot

Comment: It's best for you to try and figure this out for yourself if you can! I suppose that you're happy with the proof that all the $x_{i}$ must be equal. Suppose we call their common value $\lambda$. Then we have a constraint on $\lambda$ (obtained from the constraint on the $x_{i}$). What is that constraint? What is the value of $f$ under this constraint?